# Java child object stored in parent variable. why it's calling child method instead of calling the parent method?

Tags: java, oop

```
class Mom{
    public String sex(){
        return "Female";
    }
}
class Son extends Mom{
    @Override
    public String sex(){
        return "Male";
    }
}
```

Mom mom=new Son();

Now why mom.sex() returning "Male" should it not return "Female". I'm confused.

Because according to my thinking.It's overriden in child class logic.Shouldn't it act as the parent class logic in this context?

Comment: Nope; that's not how it works. Think of it this way: if it worked the way you wanted you couldn't implement `aShape.area()` and have it call the correct `area` impl for `Circle`, `Square`, etc.

Comment: This is exactly what *overriding* means.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `sex` inherited from `Mom` to `Son` does not seem to be a good design.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have overridden the method in child class, the implementation of child class will get higher priority over parent class. That is how `Override` works. If you remove the overridden implementation then parent class i.e. `Mom` implementation will be triggered.

Remember left hand side of `=` shows the type of object whereas right hand side of `=` represents the concrete implementation.

Comment: Is it possible anyhow to call sex() method of mom from that reference?

Comment: You can invoke the parent class method by using the `super` keyword. Your function should be updated under `John` class to `return super.sex();`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `Mom obj = new John();`, then you have created a new `John` instance. A `John` can also be used as a `Mom` because that's its super class, but when you call methods on it, they are still called on your `John` instance, where in your case you've overridden the `sex` method which's original implementation is in `Mom`.